# HTML to PDF where borders are set as a continuous stroke with a spot color

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

Have tried multiple HTML -> PDF converters, and the best results so far are with mpdf. Only problem with mpdf is that the line/stroke is not continuous when opening the PDF in a vector program like Illustrator.

In mpdf the border are split into four parts (top, bottom, left, right):

[with mpdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I8a7.png)

The line will be used as a cut countour, so it needs to be continuous. In solutions like Docraptor og wkhtmltopdf the problem is that borders are not converted as strokes, but a filled element with a solid color:

[with Docraptor or wkhtmltopdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39ym9.png)

Is there any other solutions to this - other libraries etc. that might give me the preferred output og a continuous stroke with a spot color that anyone know about?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but I have always used https://tcpdf.org/ for generating PDFs and have found that it supports everything I have ever needed.

Comment: Are you sure that with mpdf the stroke is not continuous? I.e. have you selected only part of the path in Illustrator? PDF can only draw cubic bezier curves, so rounded corners will sometimes consist of multiple curves. And the whole border will always consist of several sub-elements that together form a single path.

Comment: Yes, with mpdf the rounded rectangle is made up of four parts when opened in a vector program. This causes an issue when the line is supposed to be a cut line for machines. The elements together form a correct path, but they are not continuous.

Comment: Might add that I’m creating the borders with CSS: border: 0.25pt solid #000; border-radius: 10px;